# Should the reputation total reputation table be extended from 100,000+?

Tags: discussion, reputation-leagues

Well, the title basically covers it.

Here's SO's score table, it's capped to 100,000 +:

[image]

I am aware this would show a `0` count for other sites, although, [not all sites show the same maximum (50,000+)](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/49/month/cooking/2019-07-01?sort=reputationchange) for some reason. There is also [another site](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/174/month/graphicdesign/2019-07-01?sort=reputationchange) with `1` in the top range.

[Here's the SO link](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/alltime/stackoverflow)

My question on meta are usually very ill rewarded, so I am curious what you think.

---

So my point is, the 100,000+ cap seems arbitrary. I am nowhere near that score so other than this curiosity I don't gain anything from it. I just wondered if there is a reason for it.

---

Additionally, it also be extended with 200,000+ or 500,000+ and so on... or so... still: just wondering. By the way, I didn't spot a `0` count in one of the sites (yet)

Comment: Out of curiosity, would this affect any sites besides Stack Overflow? Have any users besides Jon Skeet attained over 1 million rep points on a single site? (I'm guessing not, but I haven't checked.) If not, this wouldn't really do anything in the immediate future. . .

Comment: I understand your argument, and that's why I linked examples of similar cases in different sites, which IMO are equal. Some are capped differently, and some have only one at the top. Aside the factor 10, the scenario is equal. I was just wondering since there are differences on the various sites so it seems to be configurable.

Comment: @HDE226868, it won't do anything in the immediate future, but in the next two years, there'll be another four SO users with a million rep, with another three or four coming up every year after that.

Comment: About time for 250K and 500K, for the same reason 25K and 50K, came into existence.

Answer (score 2):

What problem would this solve? How many users have actually achieved 1,000,000 rep? How many users *other than Jon Skeet* have done so?

IMHO we already treat rep milestones with too much fanfare. Giving additional recognition for this rarely-achieved but otherwise non-important achievement seems excessive. Jon Skeet is...Jon Skeet. He is already famous. I'm not sure what an additional "I am <s>Iron Man</s> Jon Skeet" reward will do.

Comment: I understand your argument, and that's why I linked examples of similar cases in different sites, which IMO are equal. Some are capped differently, and some have only one at the top. Aside the factor 10, the scenario is equal. I was just wondering since there are differences on the various sites so it seems to be configurable.

Comment: Why not extend it to 500,000+? There are many more viable cases for that on SO and other sites.

Comment: Ehh, well... that's a good one :-)